# How to update Api without making an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update and display Api value whenever new POST request is create, without refreshing the page. 
Here is the problem, In my React hook implementation when I make an **API** call it create's an infinite **Api** call to the server. I just want it to make a call when new POST request is added.

**What I'm doing wrong and How to fix it?**

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = () => {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/api/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                const data = res.map((item, index) => ({
                    title: item.title,
                    price: item.price,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                }));
                setData(data);
            });
        };

        console.log(data)
        fetchData();

    },[data]);
```

Full Code `App.js`

```
export default function OrderPreview(props) {

    const classes = useStyles();

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = () => {
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/api/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((res) => {
                const data = res.map((item, index) => ({
                    title: item.title,
                    price: item.price,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                }));
                setData(data);
            });
        };

        console.log(data)
        fetchData();

    },[data]);

    return (
        <main className={clsx(classes.content, {
                [classes.contentShift]: props.openstate, })}>
            <Grid container >
                <Grid item sm={12} >
                    <TableContainer className={classes.tableStyle}>
                        <Table>
                            <TableHead>
                                <TableRow>
                                    <TableCell align='center' >#</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell style={{paddingLeft:'90px'}} >Name</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align='center' >Quantity</TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align='center' >Price</TableCell>
                                </TableRow>
                            </TableHead>
                            <TableBody >
                                {data.map((item, index) => (
                                    <TableRow key={index}>
                                        <TableCell align='center' >{index + 1}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell style={{paddingLeft:'90px'}} >{item.title}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align='center' >{item.quantity}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align='center' >$ {item.price * item.quantity}</TableCell>
                                    </TableRow>


                                ))}
                                <TableCell colSpan={3} align='right' style={{paddingRight:'20px'}}> Total Price</TableCell>
                                <TableCell align='center' > non </TableCell>
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </main>
    );


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to keep fetching API, just remove `data` in the dependency array.

You are having `setData(data);` inside your `useEffect` so it will just keep running re-render over again result in `useEffect` and `setData(data)`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/api/")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.map((item, index) => ({
          title: item.title,
          price: item.price,
          quantity: item.quantity,
        }));
        setData(data);
      });
  };

  console.log(data);
  fetchData();
}, []); // <-- REMOVE DATA HERE
```

Comment: But then the the page won't re-render when a new POST request is made without refreshing the page.

Comment: What do you mean by `new POST request`? And where does it come from?

Comment: I'am creating POST request to the API containing new items details then i want it to display all the details, without refreshing the page. Its like a shop checkout system to give you a idea.

Comment: I see, so the new item probably in your props, right?

Comment: yes kinda, when a item is physically scan it create's a request, then the site displays it . is there any alternative that i can re render at the same time without causing infinite loop

Comment: I would need to see more code to be specific but one way to get around this problem is by creating a hook `const [rerender, setRerender] = useState(false);`within the same component as the one with the `useEffect` and `fetch`. Then add `rerender` to the useEffect's dependency array and add `setRerender(!rerender)` to the event handler that is changing the data (not the fetch!), most likely an onClick for adding items.

Comment: @Danesvarmen After the scan is finished, what happened after that? Are there any variable changes?